# How to round doubles to a specified decimal place without Libraries?

Tags: java, rounding

Basically I'm supposed to write a method, that uses a double "x" and an int "y" and rounds (>=5 upwards, <5 downwards) "x" to the decimal place specified by y (between 1-8). The method is supposed to return a double. However since I just started I don't have a clue how to achieve this. The exercise prior to this one way easier.

If read answers to similar question but they are not quit what I need, because I can't use the Math library or other libraries. I'm allowed to make auxiliary methods to substitute this.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Java, Eclipse as IDE

Answer (score 2):

Rounding like that with double isn't going to work.  Doubles and floats are represented with a fixed number of bits of data, and work in binary not decimal.  That means that some numbers can't be represented.  .1 can't be stored exactly.

In order to do this, you need to do use BigDecimal, which is a class that can store any exact number.  Math using BigDecimal is less efficient, but it doesn't have the accuracy issues of doubles.

Comment: I noticed that using BigDecimal requires an import. Which I'm not allowed to use either.

Comment: Then what your teacher is asking is literally impossible in the confines of the language, or you misunderstand the assignment.

Comment: Since this is a school assignment-  convert the double to a string, then take the substring of the proper size, round it appropriately based on the next character (which may require you to change multiple numbers if it goes from 9 to 0) while still using characters for each digit, then convert back to a double.  But remember if you ever did that in the real world you'd have the code review immediately rejected, it's horrible code.

Comment: The Assignment states: Implement a static public method with the name "roundDouble". Input parameters are a double "x" and an int "y" and it returns a double. The method is supposed to round the given double to the decimal place indicated by "y". Negatives are negligible. Examples: roundDouble(19.65782, 1) --> 19.7 or roundDouble(2.9843, 3) --> 2.984

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that exactly as I said is not possible in Java.  You can't have 2.984 as a double.  it would look like 2.9839879989898 or something like that.  doubles don't work in base 10

Comment: When I print it it looks fine but idk. Seems like I need to wait and see what was supposed to be done but thanks for your time.

Comment: That's because System.out.println has code in it to truncate things, it's meant for display.

Comment: Here's a nice article on the issue I mentioned https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This answers another thing I noticed today. Nice but now I'm very confused what the hell they want us to do.

Comment: My guess is whoever designed this doesn't understand floating point, and that being able to round 1.22 down to the closest number to 1.20 is probably good enough even if it isn't exactly right.